# ASP.NET - RequiredFieldValidator to validate only particular controls

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a web form. There are many different sections. I can say that each section displays data of a datatable. At each section I have OK and Cancel buttons. When I press OK any changes to the table in the database takes place. I've also put some Requiredfieldvalidators. Let's say I'm inserting a new record in the section one and the fields are correctly typed. When I press OK I get error message raised by the rest of the validators that are on the other sections. Isn't there any way that when I press OK button of a particular section to get validation errors of that same area? So what I probably need is a button that will not serve as the hole page submitter but rather a submitter of a specific section.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place a `ValidationGroup` on the `RequiredFieldValidator`'s. Then place the same `ValidationGroup` on the correct submit button. When its clicked, only validation controls that are a part of the group are validated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think janhartmann is correct ValidationGroup can help you solve the issue.Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1368/ASP-NET-validation-in-groups)